# Networks Drive - Thumbnails

Tags: pantheon-files

I have now started using ElementaryOS daily.  Everything is going very well.  I do have two things I need to figure out.

1st. This one is a must have.  I need to have thumbnails when I browse a networked drive.  I deal with image files a lot during my work day.  These are usually named something like WO65280.jpg.  I use thumbnail view so that it is easy for me to find what I am looking for.  I know it's possible.  I have seen it in other distros. I just don't know how to turn it on in Elementary OS.

2nd. A would like to have.  Folder views in Elementary OS are a one size fits all.  Setup your pictures folder the way you like and all other folders Music, Videos all will get the same settings.  It would be nice for each folder to be able to have it's own view settings.  Again I know it's possible.  Other distros do this.  Is this not possible in ElementaryOS?  Is it something coming soon?

Everything else I have needed to do in Elementary has worked.  Has been easy to discover and setup.  Overall I am really able to get my daily work done using Elementary.  Overall much better than other distros I have tired.  The thumbnail view on network drives is a must have though.  The one file view fits all is rather annoying and somewhat a mystery to me as to why Elementary OS would do that.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to show remote thumbnails by right-clicking on the background of the view and choosing "Show Remote Thumbnails".

By "one size fits all" I assume you mean the zoom level, i.e. the icon size? It is true that there is only one zoom level setting for each of the three view modes. This is true also of other Gtk based file managers (in Bionic) such as the archetypal Nautilus.  It is possible that Windows, MacOS or KDE might implement zoom per tab? This is in the process of being implemented for Terminal so could be implemented for Files also.  It would be more difficult (but possible) to implement zoom setting per folder.  Please raise an issue on https://github.com/elementary/files/issues so the extent of support can be gauged.

Comment: The ethos of elementary is to keep things as simple as possible, both in the interface and the underlying code so feature such as zoom per tab would not be implemented unless there were significant demand from users for it.  I cannot see an existing issue raised for this.

Comment: Thank you Jeremy for your answer.  That has worked for me and I am grateful.  I have added the feature request as suggested.  Have a great day.

Comment: Jeremy, this seems to have worked great for picture files.  But, not for thumbnails of video files.  Is this a bug?  Or, have I missed something?

Comment: Files does not impose a limit on the type and size of file for which it requests a thumbnail but the actual thumbnailing is done by an system service (tumbler) which has different backends for different file types.  It is possible that either the size of the file or the type of network connection protocol is preventing remote video thumbnailing.  I could not get a thumbnail of an .mpg file over an FTP connection for example.